# How can I logically invert a stack by a method that works in O(1)?

Tags: data-structures, stack, big-o

I wrote the following stack code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Stack 
{
    T *sptr;
    int cap;
    int top;
    
public:
    Stack ()
    {
        sptr = nullptr;
        top = -1;
        cap = 0;
    }
    
    void push (const T& obj)
    {
        if (top == -1)
        {
            sptr = new T[1];
            cap = 1;
            sptr[++top] = obj;
        }
        else if (cap == (top + 1))
        {
            cap *= 2;
            T *temp = new T[cap];
            for (int i = 0; i <= top; i++)
                temp[i] = sptr[i];
            temp[++top] = obj;
            delete [] sptr;
            sptr = temp;
            temp = nullptr;
        }
        else
        {
            sptr[++top] = obj;
        }
    }
    
    inline bool empty () const
    {
        return (top == -1);
    }
    
    inline int size () const
    {
        return (top + 1);
    }
    
    const T& peek () 
    {
        return sptr[top];
    }
    
    void pop ()
    {
        if (top >= 0)
        {
            if (top == 0)
            {
                top = -1;
                cap = 0;
                delete [] sptr;
            }
            else if (top >= (cap/2 -1))
            {
                top--;
            }
            else
            {
                cap /= 2;
                T *temp = new T [cap];
                for (int i = 0; i < top; i++)
                {
                    temp[i] = sptr[i];
                }
                delete [] sptr;
                sptr = temp;
                temp = nullptr;
                top--;
            }
        }
    }
    
    /*void flip() // flip method
    {
        
    }*/
};
```

Now I want to implement flip method that will logically invert the stack such that the oldest element becomes the newest element so the next pop will remove the element that was at the bottom of the stack before it had been flipped. And I should be able to flip again and again in O(1).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to reverse a real stack in O(1).

The best you can do is O(n). To see that you only have to observe, that to get the bottom element of the stack you need to pop it n times.

Howwever, you can do that in O(n):

What you can do it to create another stack, pop the content, pushing on the other. When the original is empty, drop that, and return the new stack.

UPDATE: However, you implementation is backed by an array, which is strictly stonger than a stack.

You can reverse it by keeping a direction flag, and when a revese is asked for swithing the head to tail, reversing the flag, and also the traversal direction. There will also be some additional bookkeeping for memory management, as you might have to extend both high and low.

I suggest to create a drawing of the datastructure, so that you can keep track on what happens with the offsets.

For a similar, but fixed size structre you can have a look at this: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3479/The-Bip-Buffer-The-Circular-Buffer-with-a-Twist

Comment: Will that work in O(1) as OP is asking? I think that's O(n).

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a Deque, which allows you to add and remove elements from both ends:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-ended_queue

To use it as a reversible stack, you just keep a Boolean variable to determine which end the stack operations will work with.